# Gulp: copy files and then delete part of them

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp

I basically need to copy all files under the 'api' path into a 'dist' path, and then remove the 'api/v1/_old' package in the dist path. But I cannot manage to do that :(

This is my code:

```
gulp.task('package', function() {
    var packagePath = paths.packagePath;
    var stream = gulp
                    .src( paths.api )
                    .pipe( gulp.dest( packagePath + '/api' ) );
    del( packagePath + '/api/v1/_old' );                
    return stream;  
});
```

Also, if I may, is there any way to copy also hidden files ( e.g. .htaccess ) as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your del is out of the pipeline, so it might start before the files are in the destination folder.

You should use another package such as gulp-clean, and put the cleaning in another task with a dependency on the package task. You can see examples [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-clean).

Comment: The [blacklist](https://github.com/gulpjs/plugins/blob/master/src/blackList.json) tells gulp users to use `del` rather than `gulp-clean`.